# Adapt secondary axis with sec_axis() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, yaxis

I'm struggling a bit to get the secondary axis the way I want.

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 
19727, 19728, 19729, 19730, 19731, 19732, 19733, 19734, 19735, 
19736, 19737, 19738, 19739, 19740, 19741, 19742, 19743, 19744, 
19745, 19746, 19747, 19748, 19749, 19750, 19751, 19752, 19753, 
19754, 19755, 19756, 19757, 19758, 19759, 19760, 19761, 19762, 
19763, 19764, 19765), class = "Date"), tmin = c(3.8, 2.8, 8.1, 
8.2, 4.6, 3.6, 1.8, -0.8, 4.1, 4.7, 2.3, -0.4, 2.2, 5.8, 8.4, 
11.1, 10, 10, 3.6, 2.7, 4, 3.1, 4.4, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 9.6, 8, 7.7, 
5.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.2, 5.9, 4.6, 4.6, 5.9, NA, 8.5, 7.9, 5.3, 4.3, 
6), tmax = c(9.4, 8.2, 12.1, 10.6, 8.6, 9.6, 9.3, 6.2, 7.2, 8, 
7.6, 6.9, 9, 8.6, 13.3, 13.7, 12.3, 14.3, 10.8, 9.9, 11, 10.6, 
14.9, 17.5, 17.3, 18.8, 18, 16.3, 14.9, 13, 10.5, 16.8, 14.8, 
15.2, 16.6, 14.9, 13.7, NA, 12.6, 11.7, 11.3, 8.3, 15.7), tmean = c(6.6, 
5.5, 10.1, 9.4, 6.6, 6.6, 5.6, 2.7, 5.6, 6.4, 5, 3.2, 5.6, 7.2, 
10.8, 12.4, 11.2, 12.2, 7.2, 6.3, 7.5, 6.8, 9.6, 11.7, 11.6, 
12.4, 13.8, 12.2, 11.3, 9.4, 7.6, 10.7, 10, 10.6, 10.6, 9.8, 
9.8, NA, 10.6, 9.8, 8.3, 6.3, 10.8), pcp = c(NA, 2, 2.7, 9.7, 
0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, 4.3, 2.6, 7.5, 1.1, 12.4, 
16.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.2, 6.5, 0.4, 0.1, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-43L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is my code so far:

```
selected_year <- 2024
ggplot2::ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = date)) +
  ggplot2::geom_col(aes(y = pcp, fill = "pcp"), na.rm = TRUE) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(aes(y = tmean, color = "tmean")) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(aes(y = tmax, color = "tmax")) +
  ggplot2::geom_line(aes(y = tmin, color = "tmin")) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("pcp" = "#2c7bb6"), 
    label = paste0("Daily pcp."), guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(
    values = c("tmean" = "black", "tmin" = "blue", "tmax" = "red"), 
    label = c("tmean" = "Daily mean temp.", "tmin" = "Daily min temp.", "tmax" = "Daily max temp.")) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(
    labels = function(x) paste0(x, "ºC"),
    breaks = round(seq(from = round(min(plot_data$tmin, na.rm = TRUE) - 5), 
                       to = 45, by = 5) / 5) * 5,
    limits = c(min(plot_data$tmin, na.rm = TRUE) - 5, 45), 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~., labels = function(x) paste0(x, "mm"))
  ) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = as.numeric(seq(ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-01-15")), 
                            ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-12-31")), by = "month")),
    labels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
    limits = c(as.numeric(ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-01-01"))), 
               as.numeric(ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-12-31"))))) +
  ggthemes::theme_hc(base_size = 15) +
  ggplot2::labs(
    x = "", y = "", title = paste0("Precipitation and temperature in Madrid - Retiro ", selected_year),
    subtitle = paste0("Daily precipitation and daily mean, max and min temperatures")) +
  ggplot2::theme(
    plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 1, face = "bold", family = "sans", size = 35),
    plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 1, size = 25), 
    legend.background = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    legend.box.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = 0.75),
    legend.position = c(0.1335, 0.8),
    legend.spacing = ggplot2::unit(0, "cm"),
    legend.margin = ggplot2::margin(r = 5, l = 5, b = 5),
    legend.title = element_blank())
```

The code draws the following plot:
[image]

What I want is to draw the bars for precipitation starting at the minimum temperature showed on the label for the primary axis (temperature). In this particular case, precipitation bars should start at -5ºC. However, this might change depending on data, as some locations may have different minimum temperatures across the year.

Minimum temperature label will always be `(round(seq(from = round(min(plot_data$tmin, na.rm = TRUE) - 5), to = 45, by = 5) / 5) * 5)[1]`

EDIT:

With this other data

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(19358, 19359, 19360, 19361, 
19362, 19363, 19364, 19365, 19366, 19367, 19368, 19369, 19370, 
19371, 19372, 19373, 19374, 19375, 19376, 19377, 19378, 19379, 
19380, 19381, 19382, 19383, 19384, 19385, 19386, 19387, 19388, 
19389, 19390, 19391, 19392, 19393, 19394, 19395, 19396, 19397, 
19398, 19399, 19400, 19401, 19402, 19403, 19404, 19405, 19406, 
19407, 19408, 19409, 19410, 19411, 19412, 19413, 19414, 19415, 
19416, 19417, 19418, 19419, 19420, 19421, 19422, 19423, 19424, 
19425, 19426, 19427, 19428, 19429, 19430, 19431, 19432, 19433, 
19434, 19435, 19436, 19437, 19438, 19439, 19440, 19441, 19442, 
19443, 19444, 19445, 19446, 19447, 19448, 19449, 19450, 19451, 
19452, 19453, 19454, 19455, 19456, 19457, 19458, 19459, 19460, 
19461, 19462, 19463, 19464, 19465, 19466, 19467, 19468, 19469, 
19470, 19471, 19472, 19473, 19474, 19475, 19476, 19477, 19478, 
19479, 19480, 19481, 19482, 19483, 19484, 19485, 19486, 19487, 
19488, 19489, 19490, 19491, 19492, 19493, 19494, 19495, 19496, 
19497, 19498, 19499, 19500, 19501, 19502, 19503, 19504, 19505, 
19506, 19507, 19508, 19509, 19510, 19511, 19512, 19513, 19514, 
19515, 19516, 19517, 19518, 19519, 19520, 19521, 19522, 19523, 
19524, 19525, 19526, 19527, 19528, 19529, 19530, 19531, 19532, 
19533, 19534, 19535, 19536, 19537, 19538, 19539, 19540, 19541, 
19542, 19543, 19544, 19545, 19546, 19547, 19548, 19549, 19550, 
19551, 19552, 19553, 19554, 19555, 19556, 19557, 19558, 19559, 
19560, 19561, 19562, 19563, 19564, 19565, 19566, 19567, 19568, 
19569, 19570, 19571, 19572, 19573, 19574, 19575, 19576, 19577, 
19578, 19579, 19580, 19581, 19582, 19583, 19584, 19585, 19586, 
19587, 19588, 19589, 19590, 19591, 19592, 19593, 19594, 19595, 
19596, 19597, 19598, 19599, 19600, 19601, 19602, 19603, 19604, 
19605, 19606, 19607, 19608, 19609, 19610, 19611, 19612, 19613, 
19614, 19615, 19616, 19617, 19618, 19619, 19620, 19621, 19622, 
19623, 19624, 19625, 19626, 19627, 19628, 19629, 19630, 19631, 
19632, 19633, 19634, 19635, 19636, 19637, 19638, 19639, 19640, 
19641, 19642, 19643, 19644, 19645, 19646, 19647, 19648, 19649, 
19650, 19651, 19652, 19653, 19654, 19655, 19656, 19657, 19658, 
19659, 19660, 19661, 19662, 19663, 19664, 19665, 19666, 19667, 
19668, 19669, 19670, 19671, 19672, 19673, 19674, 19675, 19676, 
19677, 19678, 19679, 19680, 19681, 19682, 19683, 19684, 19685, 
19686, 19687, 19688, 19689, 19690, 19691, 19692, 19693, 19694, 
19695, 19696, 19697, 19698, 19699, 19700, 19701, 19702, 19703, 
19704, 19705, 19706, 19707, 19708, 19709, 19710, 19711, 19712, 
19713, 19714, 19715, 19716, 19717, 19718, 19719, 19720, 19721, 
19722), class = "Date"), tmin = c(7.8, 9, 5.9, 3.1, 3, 1.9, 2.5, 
7.7, 5.9, 3.4, 4.9, 1.7, 3.7, 1.8, 4.3, 2.9, 2.8, 2.1, 1.2, 6.6, 
3.4, 0.2, -1.8, 0.2, 0.3, -0.2, -1, -0.6, -1.6, -1.1, -1.6, 1.8, 
2.4, 0.8, 1.1, 4.5, 2.3, 2.8, 2.3, 4.2, 2, 1.3, 1.9, 2.3, 4.3, 
5.8, 3.8, 3.4, 5.8, 7.9, 9.1, 8.6, 5.9, 2.7, -0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.4, -1.8, -1.6, -1.6, 0.1, 1.4, 2.3, 4.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.9, 8.6, 
8.9, 9.8, 10.1, 7.2, 7, 9.3, 10.4, 6.5, 7.6, 7, 8.1, 8.6, 8.3, 
9.9, 8.4, 9.5, 7.2, 8.3, 10.6, 11.5, 11.2, 10.3, 5.8, 5.1, 8.3, 
5.7, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 10.6, 11.9, 11.3, 10, 6.9, 8.9, 10.1, 10.5, 
10.7, 8.9, 10.4, 11.6, 12.1, 12, 9.1, 11.6, 13.3, 13.5, 15.7, 
18.7, 16.3, 14.1, 12.1, 13.5, 16.2, 14.8, 12.2, 13.5, 16.1, 14.5, 
17.2, 13.1, 10, 10, 8.4, 9.2, 8.6, 9.7, 8.3, 9.6, 9.7, 8.8, 11.1, 
13.6, 13.5, 13.4, 13.5, 12.1, 13.3, 12.4, 12.4, 12.4, 12.6, 13.5, 
13.5, 13.4, 15.2, 16.1, 15.5, 15.8, 15.9, 14.6, 16.3, 16.9, 17.1, 
15.1, 15.6, 17.9, 19.9, 20.9, 20.3, 18.5, 19.2, 16.2, 15.4, 19.6, 
21.1, 23.1, 22.3, 22.3, 22.9, 19.6, 16.7, 17.9, 20.2, 22.3, 20.5, 
21.3, 21.6, 21.4, 19.7, 19.3, 21.5, 23.6, 21.3, 21.4, 22.8, 21.1, 
20.4, 22.2, 25, 25.3, 20.9, 20.7, 19.3, 19.8, 19.2, 17.4, 18.1, 
21.2, 19.8, 21, 22.4, 23.4, 21.2, 22.1, 20.9, 15.8, 15.6, 20.1, 
19, 22.6, 24.2, 22.8, 23.5, 23.4, 23.4, 22.3, 20.3, 19.9, 20.9, 
20.6, 21.3, 21.8, 25, 24.7, 25.7, 24.1, 22.9, 19.9, 16.1, 15.1, 
17.1, 16.2, 17.4, 18.4, 15.4, 15.4, 16.1, 16.7, 18.1, 19.9, 20.3, 
19.3, 18.5, 17.1, 17.5, 16.5, 18.4, 15.5, 16, 14.9, 14.5, 13.6, 
13.5, 14.4, 11.7, 10.7, 12.7, 13.5, 15.6, 16.1, 15.4, 15.7, 18.4, 
18.1, 17.4, 17.1, 17.3, 17.4, 18, 18.2, 17, 16.7, 16, 15.2, 13.7, 
15.9, 14.9, 13.5, 14.9, 15.7, 15.6, 10.9, 10.5, 7.8, 10.2, 10.2, 
9.1, 11.8, 11.6, 9.3, 11.7, 12.5, 8.7, 7.5, 8.3, 7.1, 7.1, 9.7, 
8.5, 5.2, 3.4, 4.9, 9.6, 7.9, 11.5, 11.9, 11.6, 10.3, 10.5, 10.8, 
10.9, 8.3, 8.3, 7.6, 7.5, 7.1, 3, 3.1, 3.3, 4.9, 5.2, 7.1, 11, 
12.1, 5.8, 4.1, 1.8, 4.9, 4.9, 2.9, 3.6, 5.9, 5.8, 10.4, 9, 7.7, 
6.6, 2.6, 4.8, 2, 1.9, 1.3, 1.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.2, 2.5, 1.9, 0.7, 
0.4, -0.2, 0.9, 3.7, 1.8, 5), tmax = c(14.8, 11.8, 12.1, 11.6, 
11.6, 10.5, 7.9, 13.2, 12.7, 10.5, 9.2, 10.6, 11.1, 10.3, 11.2, 
10.1, 9.9, 5.9, 7.7, 13.7, 9.8, 8.4, 8.5, 5.7, 9.1, 9.2, 8.6, 
9.3, 5.9, 8.2, 10.9, 11.8, 12.7, 15.2, 17, 16.2, 10.8, 8.4, 9.9, 
10.3, 9, 10.4, 11.2, 10, 10.3, 12.5, 14.1, 14.8, 14.3, 17.8, 
19, 17.5, 15.7, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 11.4, 6.7, 8.9, 6.2, 9.9, 11.9, 
12.4, 10.3, 13.4, 15.5, 15.8, 17.2, 18.7, 19.8, 20.6, 19.9, 17.2, 
19.3, 22.8, 16.5, 15.6, 18, 19.8, 20.9, 21.6, 21.2, 19, 20.7, 
20.7, 19.9, 22.9, 25.2, 22, 20.9, 19.1, 18.5, 19.3, 20.7, 21.1, 
23.3, 24.2, 26, 26.5, 26.2, 25.9, 20, 15.9, 19.3, 23.3, 24, 25.1, 
22.9, 23.8, 27, 25.5, 20.5, 23.3, 25.1, 27.8, 28.9, 30.7, 30.9, 
25.5, 24.2, 26.6, 27.9, 29.1, 25.4, 26.5, 28, 27, 29, 27.1, 24.9, 
22.8, 19.4, 20.7, 20.6, 21.7, 22.4, 23.8, 22.6, 21.8, 20.5, 21.5, 
23.9, 25.2, 25.1, 25.1, 17.9, 21.5, 18.5, 23.5, 23.2, 25.2, 25.1, 
24.1, 25.3, 26.6, 28, 28.5, 22, 20.3, 24.1, 26.8, 27.9, 28.3, 
24.4, 27, 30.4, 32.5, 34, 30.8, 29.9, 27.4, 28.3, 29, 32.2, 34.2, 
37, 37, 34.9, 34.9, 36.6, 29.3, 31.7, 34.7, 35.1, 33.5, 33, 33.7, 
34.2, 32.7, 34.2, 37.8, 38, 33.2, 35.1, 36.8, 32.3, 34, 38.7, 
38.5, 37.5, 36.4, 31.9, 31.7, 36.3, 32.5, 31.9, 32.9, 34.2, 34, 
36.6, 36.8, 36.6, 36.6, 35.7, 32.8, 29, 33, 36.3, 36.5, 37.8, 
39.5, 38, 38.8, 37.9, 37.8, 36.2, 36.6, 36.3, 36.2, 34.4, 36.7, 
38, 40, 39.7, 38.9, 39, 37.8, 31.5, 23.8, 27.2, 28.9, 27.8, 31.4, 
31.6, 23.2, 20.9, 23.3, 27.3, 27.6, 29, 29.4, 27.4, 28.9, 26, 
27, 27.3, 26.7, 24.3, 22.2, 19.2, 20, 23.2, 23.9, 18.6, 20.5, 
22.2, 25.3, 27.8, 27, 27.1, 28.2, 29.9, 29.2, 30, 29, 29, 26.8, 
29.2, 30.1, 29, 29, 27.5, 26.4, 26.3, 26.7, 25.3, 21.2, 21.1, 
20, 23.2, 20.6, 16.7, 15.8, 16.2, 15.5, 14.8, 13.2, 17.2, 18.2, 
15, 16.6, 16.3, 15.9, 12.6, 14.3, 15.9, 13.1, 13.9, 13.4, 12.9, 
10.1, 11.5, 15.5, 14.6, 17.6, 18.6, 18, 15.8, 15.7, 13.7, 16.1, 
17.1, 17.5, 17.3, 13.2, 13.5, 13.7, 14.8, 15.5, 13.2, 10.8, 12, 
13.7, 14.6, 12.5, 10, 7.5, 10.1, 8.1, 9.1, 8.6, 11.6, 12.7, 12.1, 
12.8, 12.1, 11.3, 11.1, 13.1, 11.1, 11.4, 11, 10.9, 11.9, 11.6, 
13.1, 12.6, 10.8, 9.7, 8.3, 9.3, 7.1, 8.5, 10.7, 9.4), tmean = c(11.3, 
10.4, 9, 7.4, 7.3, 6.2, 5.2, 10.4, 9.3, 7, 7, 6.2, 7.4, 6, 7.8, 
6.5, 6.4, 4, 4.4, 10.2, 6.6, 4.3, 3.4, 3, 4.7, 4.5, 3.8, 4.4, 
2.2, 3.6, 4.6, 6.8, 7.6, 8, 9, 10.4, 6.6, 5.6, 6.1, 7.2, 5.5, 
5.8, 6.6, 6.2, 7.3, 9.2, 9, 9.1, 10, 12.8, 14, 13, 10.8, 6.2, 
4.7, 5, 5.8, 3.6, 3.6, 2.3, 4.2, 6, 6.9, 6.3, 9, 12, 12.6, 14, 
13.6, 14.4, 15.2, 15, 12.2, 13.2, 16, 13.4, 11, 12.8, 13.4, 14.5, 
15.1, 14.8, 14.4, 14.6, 15.1, 13.6, 15.6, 17.9, 16.8, 16, 14.7, 
12.2, 12.2, 14.5, 13.4, 16.2, 16.7, 17.6, 18.6, 19, 18.6, 15, 
11.4, 14.1, 16.7, 17.2, 17.9, 15.9, 17.1, 19.3, 18.8, 16.2, 16.2, 
18.4, 20.6, 21.2, 23.2, 24.8, 20.9, 19.2, 19.4, 20.7, 22.6, 20.1, 
19.4, 20.8, 21.6, 21.8, 22.2, 19, 16.4, 14.7, 14.6, 14.9, 15.2, 
16, 16, 16.1, 15.8, 14.6, 16.3, 18.8, 19.4, 19.2, 19.3, 15, 17.4, 
15.4, 18, 17.8, 18.9, 19.3, 18.8, 19.4, 20.9, 22, 22, 18.9, 18.1, 
19.4, 21.6, 22.4, 22.7, 19.8, 21.3, 24.2, 26.2, 27.4, 25.6, 24.2, 
23.3, 22.2, 22.2, 25.9, 27.6, 30, 29.6, 28.6, 28.9, 28.1, 23, 
24.8, 27.4, 28.7, 27, 27.2, 27.6, 27.8, 26.2, 26.8, 29.6, 30.8, 
27.2, 28.2, 29.8, 26.7, 27.2, 30.4, 31.8, 31.4, 28.6, 26.3, 25.5, 
28, 25.8, 24.6, 25.5, 27.7, 26.9, 28.8, 29.6, 30, 28.9, 28.9, 
26.8, 22.4, 24.3, 28.2, 27.8, 30.2, 31.8, 30.4, 31.2, 30.6, 30.6, 
29.2, 28.4, 28.1, 28.6, 27.5, 29, 29.9, 32.5, 32.2, 32.3, 31.6, 
30.4, 25.7, 20, 21.2, 23, 22, 24.4, 25, 19.3, 18.2, 19.7, 22, 
22.8, 24.4, 24.8, 23.4, 23.7, 21.6, 22.2, 21.9, 22.6, 19.9, 19.1, 
17, 17.2, 18.4, 18.7, 16.5, 16.1, 16.4, 19, 20.6, 21.3, 21.6, 
21.8, 22.8, 23.8, 24, 23.2, 23, 22, 23.3, 24, 23.6, 23, 22.1, 
21.2, 20.8, 20.2, 20.6, 18, 17.3, 17.4, 19.4, 18.1, 13.8, 13.2, 
12, 12.8, 12.5, 11.2, 14.5, 14.9, 12.2, 14.2, 14.4, 12.3, 10, 
11.3, 11.5, 10.1, 11.8, 11, 9, 6.8, 8.2, 12.6, 11.2, 14.6, 15.2, 
14.8, 13, 13.1, 12.2, 13.5, 12.7, 12.9, 12.4, 10.4, 10.3, 8.4, 
9, 9.4, 9, 8, 9.6, 12.4, 13.4, 9.2, 7, 4.6, 7.5, 6.5, 6, 6.1, 
8.8, 9.2, 11.2, 10.9, 9.9, 9, 6.8, 9, 6.6, 6.6, 6.2, 6, 6.8, 
6.9, 7.6, 7.6, 6.4, 5.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 6.1, 6.2, 7.2), pcp = c(0.1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.3, 4.2, NA, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4, 
0.2, NA, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4.2, 0.5, 1.8, 14.3, 1.1, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 7.3, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.9, 0.7, 4.8, NA, 18.8, 6.3, 10.4, 7.4, 7.2, 0.6, 
NA, 8.3, 1, 0.2, NA, 4.5, 2.9, 9.8, 3.3, NA, NA, NA, 1.8, 0.1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.6, 0.5, NA, 7.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 31.2, 66.5, 9.1, 6.2, NA, NA, 2.8, 3.6, 7.6, NA, NA, NA, 
18.2, 13.3, 0.3, 6.3, NA, NA, NA, 0.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.4, 
NA, 2.9, 0.8, 2.4, 6.8, 107.8, NA, NA, 41.2, 2.2, 1.8, NA, 3.9, 
NA, 2, 6.1, 0.3, NA, 1.4, 17.9, 1, 1.5, NA, NA, 0.3, 0.9, NA, 
2.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14.2, NA, NA, 
0.1, NA, 3.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -365L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And using @L Tyrone's answer I'm getting the following plot:

[image]

Where you can see right axis for precipitation is messed up. The only modification I tried to do was to define `l.y.max` and `r.y.min` not as a fixed value but a dynamic value that changes with data:

```
l.y.max <- round((max(plot_data$pcp, na.rm = TRUE) + 10) / 5) * 5
r.y.min <- round((min(plot_data$tmin, na.rm = TRUE) - 5) / 5) * 5
```

Comment: Perhaps just a question-simplification thing, but you're equating `-5ºC` with precisely `-5mm`, is that intentional? Or do you have some translation you have omitted (for simplicity) from this question?

Comment: If I copy the `breaks=round(...)` expression and add it to `sec_axis(..)`, it shows all second-y-labels. Is this what you need?

Comment: `-5ºC` equating `-5mm` is just coincidence. Precisely what I want is `-5ºC` equating `0mm` (in the case of the data shared in the question). Ideally `(round(seq(from = round(min(plot_data$tmin, na.rm = TRUE) - 5), to = 45, by = 5) / 5) * 5)[1]` should equal `0mm` given any data

Comment: Perhaps I'm confusing your need then. Do you have a formula to translate from `ºC` to `mm`? If so, you need to use it, and that will have an impact on what breaks are shown.

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue you have with the 2023 data. Changing only the source data, l.y.max and r.y.min to your new values, and selected_year to 2023, I get [this plot](https://imgur.com/a/02ooPmD). I note that on your 2023 plot, the max value on your left y-axis is 45 instead of the original 50, so something else has changed other than  l.y.max and r.y.min.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my fault, I had changes in `scale_y_continuous()` `breaks` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge arises when plotting two ranges of values and one is positve-only, and the other is both positive and negative. Here's a possible solution. It involves scaling your temperature values relative to your precipitation values *prior to plotting*. I find making nicely aligned axes ticks and labels easier with this method.

I have arbitrarily set the ymin/ymax values of each y-axis based on your sample data. Given you are likely to be creating multiple plots with potentially different ranges, it makes sense to have a fixed y-axis values to allow 'fair' comparisons between plots.

However, there's nothing stopping you modifying the y-axes limits based on your "minimum temperature" formula. If you do, you'll need to change the `l.y.min`, `l.y.max`, `r.y.min`, and `r.y.max` values accordingly. But the other advantage of the limit values used in this example is that the y-axes ticks and labels line up 'tidily'. If you choose custom limits, you may have to adjust the number of breaks in order to get nicely aligned ticks.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

# Your data
plot_data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19723, 19724, 19725, 19726, 
19727, 19728, 19729, 19730, 19731, 19732, 19733, 19734, 19735, 
19736, 19737, 19738, 19739, 19740, 19741, 19742, 19743, 19744, 
19745, 19746, 19747, 19748, 19749, 19750, 19751, 19752, 19753, 
19754, 19755, 19756, 19757, 19758, 19759, 19760, 19761, 19762, 
19763, 19764, 19765), class = "Date"), tmin = c(3.8, 2.8, 8.1, 
8.2, 4.6, 3.6, 1.8, -0.8, 4.1, 4.7, 2.3, -0.4, 2.2, 5.8, 8.4, 
11.1, 10, 10, 3.6, 2.7, 4, 3.1, 4.4, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 9.6, 8, 7.7, 
5.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.2, 5.9, 4.6, 4.6, 5.9, NA, 8.5, 7.9, 5.3, 4.3, 
6), tmax = c(9.4, 8.2, 12.1, 10.6, 8.6, 9.6, 9.3, 6.2, 7.2, 8, 
7.6, 6.9, 9, 8.6, 13.3, 13.7, 12.3, 14.3, 10.8, 9.9, 11, 10.6, 
14.9, 17.5, 17.3, 18.8, 18, 16.3, 14.9, 13, 10.5, 16.8, 14.8, 
15.2, 16.6, 14.9, 13.7, NA, 12.6, 11.7, 11.3, 8.3, 15.7), tmean = c(6.6, 
5.5, 10.1, 9.4, 6.6, 6.6, 5.6, 2.7, 5.6, 6.4, 5, 3.2, 5.6, 7.2, 
10.8, 12.4, 11.2, 12.2, 7.2, 6.3, 7.5, 6.8, 9.6, 11.7, 11.6, 
12.4, 13.8, 12.2, 11.3, 9.4, 7.6, 10.7, 10, 10.6, 10.6, 9.8, 
9.8, NA, 10.6, 9.8, 8.3, 6.3, 10.8), pcp = c(NA, 2, 2.7, 9.7, 
0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, 4.3, 2.6, 7.5, 1.1, 12.4, 
16.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.2, 6.5, 0.4, 0.1, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-43L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Set min and max limits for left y-axis
l.y.min <- 0
l.y.max <- 40

# Set min and max limits for right y-axis
r.y.min <- -10
r.y.max <- 50

# Function to scale right y-axis values (temperature in this case)
axis_scaled <- function(x) {
  y <- ifelse(is.na(x), NA,
              ((x - r.y.min) / (r.y.max - r.y.min)) * 
                (l.y.max - l.y.min) + l.y.min)
  y <- y[2:(length(y)-1)]
}

# create copy of plot_data with scaled temperature values
plot_data1 <- plot_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(tmin:tmean), list(~ axis_scaled(c(r.y.min, ., r.y.max))))

# Create breaks for left and right y-axis, and labels for right y-axis
l.y.labels <- paste0(seq(r.y.min, r.y.max, 5), "ºC")
l.y.breaks <- seq(l.y.min, l.y.max, length.out = length(l.y.labels))
r.y.labels <- paste0(seq(l.y.min, l.y.max, 10), "mm")
r.y.breaks <- seq(l.y.min, l.y.max, length.out = length(r.y.labels))

selected_year <- 2024

# Plot
ggplot(data = plot_data1, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = pcp, fill = "pcp")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = tmean, color = "tmean")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = tmax, color = "tmax")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = tmin, color = "tmin")) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("pcp" = "#2c7bb6"), 
    label = paste0("Daily pcp."), guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("tmean" = "black", "tmin" = "blue", "tmax" = "red"), 
    label = c("tmean" = "Daily mean temp.", "tmin" = "Daily min temp.", 
              "tmax" = "Daily max temp.")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = l.y.breaks,
                     limits = c(l.y.min, l.y.max),
                     labels = l.y.labels,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .,
                                         breaks = r.y.breaks, 
                                         labels = r.y.labels)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = as.numeric(seq(ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-01-15")), 
                            ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-12-31")), by = "month")),
    labels = month.abb[], # Saves having to type out each individual month label
    limits = c(as.numeric(ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-01-01"))), 
               as.numeric(ymd(paste0(selected_year, "-12-31"))))) +
  ggthemes::theme_hc(base_size = 15) +
  labs(
    x = "", 
    y = "", 
    title = paste0("Precipitation and temperature in Madrid - Retiro ", selected_year),
    subtitle = paste0("Daily precipitation and daily mean, max and min temperatures")) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, face = "bold", family = "sans", size = 14),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 12), 
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = 0.75),
    legend.position = c(0.1335, 0.8),
    legend.spacing = unit(0, "cm"),
    legend.margin = margin(r = 5, l = 5, b = 5),
    legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: result]

Comment: Hi @L Tyrone! Thank you so much, will have a deep look at this tonight! In the meantime I can confirm that 1-3 NA values per row are possible. I have years with dates where `tmean`, `tmax` and `tmin` are NA but `pcp` has a valid value. Ideally I would like to plot empty spaces (as in my original plot for 07-Feb-2024) whenever `tmean`, `tmax` and `tmin` are NA so that user seeing the plot knows there is missing data. If it's easier I could replace NA values for `pcp` with 0.0. Thanks again

Comment: @piblo95 - good to go. I've tested it on a modified version of plot_data that has the presence of 1, 2, 3, and all NA values in rows and it works.

Comment: @L Tyrone sorry to bother you again. I'm struggling to plot data for year 2023 where max precipitation in a day was 107mm. I've edited my original question to include this new data and a picture of the plot I'm getting